# Yii: Get value from column of a MANY_TO_MANY connectiontable into another table on the model layer

Tags: php, database, yii, many-to-many, relation

So what I want to do with yii is a littly complex.

**Database**
I have a city, a city_has_product and a product table. So city is MANY_TO_MANY with products through city_has_product. And city_has_product has a column named amount.

For knowing the FK and PK names, here the tables with FK and PKs:

**city**
id

**city_has_product**
city_id
product_id

**product**
id

**What I want as model**
I want, that I can do this: $city->products[0]->amount
So the amount value comes from city_has_product to Product (in the model layer)

**So far I am**
City has this relations:

```
return array(
  'city_has_product'=> array(self::HAS_MANY, 'CityHasProduct', 'city_id'),
  'products'=> array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Product', array('product_id'=>'id'), 'through' => 'city_has_product'),
);
```

CityHasProducts has no relation
Product has this relations:

```
return array(
 'city_has_product'=> array(self::HAS_MANY, 'CityHasProduct', 'product_id'),
 'city'=> array(self::HAS_ONE, 'City', array('city_id'=>'id'), 'through' => 'city_has_product'),
 'hasAmount' => array(self::STAT, 'CityHasProduct', 'product_id', 'select'=>'amount'),
);
```

**Problem with my solution**
hasAmount ignores the city. I tried it with 'condition'='city_id=city.id' but it didn't worked. I dont know how I can access the city.id from Product, because I have no direct relationsship with city, because on db level product and city are MANY_TO_MANY.

**Questions**
1. Is this possible as relation with yii?
2. How can I get city.id from Product?
3. Am I on the right track? If not how to get to this model I want?

Thanks for all your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

I have `table City (city_id, name)`, `table Product (product_id, name)` and `table city_has_product (city_id, product_id, amount)`. Everything look like you, right?

1/ There are `MANY to MANY` relationship, if you don't provide the `city_id` and `product_id`, you will never get amount of two objects `City` and `Product`.

2/ Okay, we need two `city_id` and `product_id`, but how you pass and make them work together in order to get amount from category_has_product? Is it like following snipet?

> $city->products[0]->amount

Oh, we got problem now, it was wrong for sure. Don't think that you got the city_id (from `$city`) and product_id (from `$product` by index 0) then `amount` should have been come up from `Product`. No, it doesn't.
Both of us knew that `amount` column was in `CityHasProduct` model, not `City` or `Product`, then `amount` was not Product or City property absolutely.

3/ You have had the relation on City and Product, but how they fit for your purpose. Let see the following query:

```
$product_id = 2;
$city_id = 4;
    $product = Product::model()->with(array(
        'cities' => array(
            'condition'=>'cities.city_id = :city_id',
            'params' => array(':city_id' => $city_id)
        )

    ))->findByAttributes(array('product_id'=>$product_id));

//it return Product model.

//or we can do samething from City model
```

But wait, what are we doing here? Why I have to implement above query then continue to find out the `Product` and `Category` when I have already known exactly the City and Product (by city_id and product_id), yeah, in this case it seems silly at all

4/ Finally, I asked myself why couldn't it be simple like below query:

> ```
> $rls = CityHasProduct::model()->findByAttributes(array( 'city_id' => $city_id, 'product_id' => $product_id));
> ```

Now you can access to both of city and product like below

```
$rts->amount;
$city = $rls->city->name; //BELONG_TO relation on CityHasProduct model
$product= $rls->product->name; //BELONG_TO relation on CityHasProduct model
```

CityHasProduct model relation should be

```
return array(
            'product' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Product',  array('product_id'=>'product_id')),
            'city' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'City',  array('city_id'=>'city_id')),
        );
```

5/ Btw, forget the way how you use self::STAT to try to make stuff work, it just gives you the count of record from CityHasProduct match with city_id or product_id

> Statistical Query
>
> Besides the relational query described above, Yii also supports the
>   so-called statistical query (or aggregational query). It refers to
>   retrieving the aggregational information about the related objects,
>   such as the number of comments for each post, the average rating for
>   each product, etc. Statistical query can only be performed for objects
>   related in HAS_MANY (e.g. a post has many comments) or MANY_MANY (e.g.
>   a post belongs to many categories and a category has many posts).
>
> Performing statistical query is very similar to performing relation
>   query as we described before. We first need to declare the statistical
>   query in the relations() method of CActiveRecord like we do with
>   relational query.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr

*** Out there still has some tricks to help you to getting over. You just add more public property name `'pamount'` on Product, then you create a function on City model
`function getProductWithAmount([index from default search $city->products])` 
and go ahead with it.

```
$amountFromProductIndex = $city->getProductWithAmount(0)->pamount;
```

However, I don't encourage you follow it.

Answer (score -1):

1. I think your relations have some problems.  You say that City - Product is Many to Many yet your relation `city` in the `Products` model is a `HAS_ONE` instead of a `HAS_MANY`. and the other issue with your relations is that you are trying to use a statistical query to get a scalar value from CityHasProducts, but statistical queries are for retrieving aggregate values like COUNT(*) or SUM(amount).
2. Since City to product is Many to Many, there is no single City for a given Product, you can however get an array of cities for a given product.  that array may only have one city in it, but it will be an array none the less.
3. you can retrieve the amount for a product given a city and product, and you can get at it from either the product or the city, your choice.

Try this:

```
$product = Product::model()->with('city_has_products')->findByAttributes(array(
    'condition' => 't.id = :city_id and cityHasProducts.poduct_id = :product_id',
    'params' = array(
        ':product_id' => $product_id,
        ':city_id' => $cty_id,
    ),
);
$amount = $product->city_has_products->amount;
```

You may have to tweak this a bit as it is untested, but it should provide a direction for you.

Comment: whether I agreed with some points in your argument, but what you has shown up is reverse. Because your code is untested, I ignore the your error typo, but it was still wrong. You even can't pass condition through findByAttributes like this, btw, how could you let $product->city_has_products access to the amount property since it has been inherently an array absolutely?

Comment: I got this off the Yii website here: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/21178-findbyattributes-example/